# How to save large amount of data within users browser?

Tags: jquery, cookies, browser

I have been writing a php script that saves a long string within cookie (more than 4000 chars long) and I want to save it within the browser cache. The problem is that almost all browsers have a limit. What should I do? I'm using jQuery for adding and reading data from cookie and php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Web Storage Portability Layer: A Common API for Web Storage](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/05/web-storage-portability-layer-common.html)

It abstracts the various local storage mechanisms that browsers provide.

Local storage is becoming standardized in HTML5.

Comment: can you please give a quick example for the lazy? :)

Comment: @Paul Annesley even though it's not probably what John's looking for, as IE is way behind it's a nice one. +1!

Comment: @Frankie actually it is what I'm looking for :D Though I need an example on how to do that... And I need to know the limits.(which I'm reading on right now) 
@Paul Annesley an example please

Comment: Actually I may have been thinking of a different abstraction library.  Either way - find one that abstracts across the various browsers you want to support.  If you only need to support modern HTML5-capable browsers, then life is good, just check out the HTML5 Web Storage docs.

Comment: This is more like what I was thinking of: http://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js

Comment: @Paul also a very nice one this on github!

Comment: Ok found answer. The answer is using "localStorage". A good example can be found at http://html5demos.com/storage

Answer (score 4):

Rethink your App logic and save most of the data on server.

This will save you a lot of hassle in the long run.

Just my two cents.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML5 based concept of IndexDb to save data at client end.

www.tipstr.in/html5-learn-use-indexeddb

Answer (score 1):

Use  http://www.jstorage.info/ this will help you  store lots of data without problems

Answer (score 0):

I know your looking for a JQuery solution, but perhaps this will give you a starting point to look for a JQuery option.  Its html 5 data storage on the client side.  10 megs in IE, and 5 megs in all other browsers.  I believe yahoo has a solution in theirs for non-HTML 5 browsers.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/storage/

Answer (score 0):

1. You can split data into more smaller cookies (you can name it in some defined continuous like abcd_0, abcd_1).
2. You can save string at server side (in database or server filesystem) and save in cookie only MD5 checksum of this string, and when you want read this string you must transport cookie value (MD5 checksum) at server side and do query in the database or search in filesystem to obitan data and transport to browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery data method to store data:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

jQuery itself uses this method to store information.

**But this will not persist the data.**

Why not store the information in a hidden field in the form? But that again is going to remain stored only until the browser is not closed.

Comment: this stores data in the DOM. Is lost after page refresh and browser navigation. How can it help him?

Comment: Thank you Frankie for pointing it that out. Sorry ovais.tariq no cigar.

Comment: lol yeah you are write., i may be didnt read the question properly, this data is not going to get cached. my bad., i have edited my answer